# Javascript function to encapsulate check if a variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a javascript library, and I have a lot of redundant checks like this:

```
if(typeof foo !== "undefined" && foo !== null)
```

So, I wanted to create a function that will be a shortcut to this unwieldy check. So I came up with this:

```
function isset(a) 
{
     return (typeof a !== "undefined" && a !== null) ? true : false;
}
```

But, since the value could be undefined, and it attempts to use a possibly undefined variable, it turns out to be useless.

Is there a way to accomplish this without have to extend a native prototype?

Comment: PS: You can shorten `return (cond) ? true : false;` to `return cond;`

Comment: @mu is too short Abstracting the DOM means that different browsers will have different functions defined, just for one example.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder I'll keep that in mind, but that function doesn't work.

Comment: By the way, this is the library: https://github.com/timw4mail/kis-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean by `undefined`.

**1. You mean the variable does not exist.**

In this case, what you want is not possible. `typeof` is an operator and therefore has magic behavior you just can't emulate using the language. If you try to pass a variable that doesn't exist to your function, it will throw a `ReferenceError`.

(See below for a workaround.)

**2. You mean the variable has the value `undefined`, but *does* exist.**

In this case, your function will do the trick -- though it could be simplified to the following:

```
function isset(variable) {
    return variable != null;
}
```

This function will return `false` if the variable is either `undefined` or `null`. It takes advantage of the fact that `undefined == null` in JavaScript. Of course, with such a short function, one could argue that the function isn't needed at all.

Recall that a variable that is *declared* has a value -- `undefined` -- by default.

---

The name of your function suggests you mean case #1. I don't know what sort of library you are writing, but I can't imagine a case in a library where you would need to check if a variable *exists*, though I can definitely think of many possibilities for case #2.

If case #1 is necessary, remember that you can re-declare variables without changing their value:

```
a = 1; // pretend this was set somewhere higher up in the code
var a; // this does not change the value of `a`
```

If you re-declare variables before you use `isset`, you could avoid the `ReferenceError` problem. You won't be able to tell if the code has already declared the variable, though; you will only be able to tell if they have not assigned it to some other value.

Comment: I want to avoid redeclaring variables. I want to check for both cases, to see if a member of an object exists, or if a function parameter is not defined.

Comment: @timw4mail: both of those fall under case #2. Function parameters default to undefined if they're left out, and as long as you're not accessing beyond the first level of an object, they default to undefined too. (`foo.test` would be undefined, but `foo.test.test` would throw an error.)

Answer (score 2):

You can check for `null` and `undefined` at the same time by using `!=` instead.

```
    // checks for both null and undefined
if( foo != null ) { ...
```

...so no need to use a function to shorten it.

Comment: Would this also match 0 or false? I want to make sure that the value is set.

Comment: @timw4mail: No. The other "falsey" values are not equal to `null`. This includes `false`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`. All these values will be considered distinct from `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: There is the one edge case if undefined is foolishly redefined, in which this wouldn't work.

Comment: @timw4mail: That shouldn't be an issue here. It doesn't rely on the global `undefined` when you do `!= null`. It would if you did `!= undefined` instead.

Comment: @timw4mail: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/PwWMK/) where `undefined` is shadowed. Comparing to `null` gives the correct result, but comparing directly to `undefined` gives an incorrect result. That's why you compare to `null`, because then the `undefined` doesn't need to be reached via the variable environment, but is rather obtained internally by the JavaScript interpreter. Whatever you end up doing, *don't* use a function for this test. It will be needlessly slow.

Answer (score 0):

`null` and `undefined` also evaluates to `false` in an `if` statement.  So the following statement also works:

```
if(!foo)
    ...
```

This should cut it down significantly.

Comment: This will catch any of the other falsy values, too. `""` and `0` are the ones I'd be specifically concerned about in library code.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid catching other falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why people keep promoting `if (var)` or `if (!var)`. Both fail in my browsers. Meantime `if (obj.prop)` passes. This means that we should use `if (this.someVar)` or `if (window.someVar)` instead of `if (varbl)`. Ok?